# Fire intent or function after audio playback ends Alexa skill node.js

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I need to perform the following sequence of events in my alexa skill and I am currently unable to determine how to do this.

1. Play some audio clip (longer than 90 seconds).
2. Ask the user if they are ready for the next audio clip.
3. Play another audio clip if requested.
4. Repeat as needed.

I have the following intent for #1 :

```
"PlayWarmUp": function(){
        console.log("play warm up intent fired");

        if (this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.Display) {
            //play warm up video
            const builder = new Alexa.templateBuilders.BodyTemplate6Builder();
            const template = builder.setTextContent(makeRichText('<font size="7">Are you ready?</font><br/><br/><br/><br/>')).build();
            let meta = {
                title: "Warmup",
                subtitle: null
            };
            this.response.playVideo(videoURL, meta).renderTemplate(template).hint("'Yes', or 'No', or 'Ready'");
            //switch state to workout since we want to handle their responses to the are you ready screen, which is in the WORKOUT state
            this.handler.state = states.WORKOUT;
            this.emit(":responseReady");
        } else {
            // Audio only
            //
            console.log("Audio only for play warm up");
            this.response.shouldEndSession(false);
            this.response.audioPlayerPlay('ENQUEUE', warmupAudioURL, 'warmup-audio-token', 'previous-token', '0');

            this.handler.state = states.WORKOUT;
            audioState = states.WARMUP;
            this.emit(":responseReady");
        }
    }
```

Amazon provide built in intents for audio events like this:

```
const audioHandlers = {
    'PlaybackStarted' : function() {
        console.log('Alexa begins playing the audio stream');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'PlaybackFinished' : function() {
        console.log('The stream comes to an end');
        console.log("audioState: ", audioState);
        console.log("this ", this);
        console.log("context: ", this.context);

        if (audioState === states.WARMUP) {
            console.log("audio state is warm up...");

            // This doesn't work. It does nothing.
            //
            this.handler.state = states.WORKOUT;
            this.emitWithState("WORKOUT");
        }
    },
    'PlaybackStopped' : function() {
        console.log('Alexa stops playing the audio stream');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'PlaybackNearlyFinished' : function() {
        console.log('The currently playing stream is nearly complate and the device is ready to receive a new stream');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'PlaybackFailed' : function() {
        console.log('Alexa encounters an error when attempting to play a stream');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};
```

The above code doesn't work. I am unable to call the "WORKOUT" intent when the audio finishes.

The [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#valid-response-types-1) states:

[image]

I've also looked at using [SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio), but `emitWithState()` fires before the speech is finished and it only allows for 90 seconds of audio.

It doesn't make sense that you can't play and audio clip and then ask the user something. This should be a basic dialogue function. Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Any update on this? Im in the same boat...

Comment: @BluishMicrobe I finished that project and never found a solution to the problem. It appears that the Alexa SDK doesn't allow for this behavior at the current time. It was version 1.0 when I checked all of this, not sure what it is now or if things have changed.

Comment: Hey you got any solution for this. Because i am also stuck here.

Comment: @NidhinSG No I never did get a solution. The [Alexa SDK is now on version 2.0](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/new-alexa-skills-kit-ask-feature-audio-streaming-in-alexa-skills) and there is some [sample code](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player), but I still don't think this is possible.

Comment: I got the same problem, didn't find solution too. SDK v2 (nor any potential future version) does not change anything because all it does is to recognize request and then compose and send response, and Alexa service (by design) won't accept speech inside response to AudioPlayer requests anyway.

Btw, it seems that Amazon increased the limit of <audio> length from 90 to 240 seconds (documentation currently says it's 240), it might have solved your problem. It's not perfect though, e.g. <audio> doesn't allow to pause/resume and looses the progress on 'Alexa, stop'

Comment: it's not much but voting here might help in the future.
https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/35481748-allow-new-skill-session-after-audio-stream-has-com